How do I remove escape characters from a JSON value in Python?
I have a big JSON data with one of the keys having escape characters like :
{"key":{"keyinner1":"\"escapeddata\"","keyinner2":"text"}}

I want to convert it to :
{"key":{"keyinner1":"escapeddata","keyinner2":"text"}}

json.loads does not work on this data , i tried using replace function but it does not work as well

I cannot duplicate your problem.  json.loads works perfectly well with that string.  There's something else going on.

if you're pasting the JSON into your script as a string literal, you can paste it as a raw string literal and then do replace():
string = r'{"key":{"keyinner1":"\"escapeddata\"","keyinner2":"text"}}'
string = string.replace('\\"', '')

